# Optimize a function of two variables whose sizes differ by orders of magnitude in python

Tags: python, optimization, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to optimize a nonlinear function, a sum of terms, that looks something like:

```
1/(x1+x1)+2/(x1+x2)+1/(x2+x2)+1/(x1+w1)+1/(x2+w1)+1/(x1+w2)+1/(x2+w2)+...
```

where the variables are *x1* and *x2* and I have a list of w's.

When testing out various sets of w's for which I know the answer, I find the optimizer I'm using (*scipy.optimize.fmin_tnc*) fails to give to correct answer for *x1* and *x2* values that are several orders of magnitudes apart.

It gives the correct answer if the values are more similar in size.

For example, a set of 2 unique and several degenerate values (given small amounts of noise):

```
w=[5e-13,5e-13,5e-13,5e-13,5e-13,5e-7,5e-7,5e-7]
```

returns values of *~5e-13* and *~2.4e-7.*

I tried adjusting the tolerances, but this doesn't seem to improve the results for this test case.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the 'rescale' flag higher than the default value(1.3) eliminates the problem. I believe this flag makes the minimizer more stable by scaling the variables so they are more similar in size.